# На мой хостинг проник вредоностный шелл, который перезаписывает htaccess — как предотвратить появление вновь?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, защита, вирусы

Приветствую. Столкнулся с проблемой - на мою учетку хостинга проник бэкдор шелл, который перезаписал все файлы htaccess на сайтах и теперь с мобильных устройств постоянно редиректит на посторонние сайты. перезапись файлов с правами 644, к сожалению, ничего не дает - через 30 минут файлы снова перезаписываются...(((
к сожалению, дату точную не знаю, когда это произошло - заметил на выходных.
Может быть, кто уже справлялся с паразитом подобного рода и знает, что делать?

На просторах иннета наткнулся на такое решение - подключиться по SSH и прописать замену:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/eval(base64_decode(\"DQplcn[^;]*;//g' {} \;
```

Как думаете - будет действенно и не навредит сайту?

**Дополнено 1:**
в ходе экспериментов - обнаружил такую особенность: на сайтах с движком wordpress (не самая последняя), в которых установлена одна и таже тема и схожие плагины (в частности интернет-магазин), загружается только главная страница, а при переходе на остальные - выкидывает 404 ошибку.. в одном из-за того, что стоит собственный плагин для авторизации пользователей - не могу попасть даже в админку. Айболит говорит про проблемы в стандартных для этой темы плагинах `evanto wordpress toolkit` и `safeguard pro`. На одном сайте их снес, но результата пока не дало..

**Дополнено 2:** 
заразу обнаружил и вытравил! с помощью [айболита](https://www.revisium.com/ai/) и почистил хвосты по рекомендациям @xaja и @Mike. Вопрос теперь: как защититься на будущее и закрыть дыру? движки сайта wordpress, обновил до последней версии - плагины наподобие AntiVirus подойдут или не спасут от шеллов?

Comment: https://www.revisium.com/ai/ найдет вирус, опробован неоднократно.

Comment: чтобы такого не происходило, для wordpress, например, советуют запретить изменение каких-либо файлов веб-серверу (это если веб-сервер у вас работает не под вашим аккаунтом). Доставляет некоторые неудобства (нельзя ставить темы/плагины или редактировать файлы из админки wp), зато повышает защищенность. Но и это не поможет, если взломали сам сервер, а не сайт, и у атакующего будет доступ к root'у сервера. Если взломали сервер - то писать саппорту или менять хостинг, т.к. взломали раз - взломают и второй

Comment: @BOPOH, взломали все сайт принадлежащие учетке. а про сервер хз и как будто когда-нитьсаппорт признается, что взломали именно сервер - скажет ваши проблемы, вы и разбирайтесь

Comment: все сайты на учетке крутятся под ним апачем? значит права на файлы у всех сайтов одни и те же, а значит не факт, что был взломан именно сервер, а не один из ваших сайтов. Т.е. взломав один сайт можно смело гулять по остальным. Поэтому, если ваша учетка отличается от учетки веб-сервера, есть шанс, что запретив апачу (или nginx'у) редактирование файлов, вы помешаете вирусу (если только не сам сервер был взломан, а то рискуете получить root на файлах без возможности изменения)))

Comment: @BOPOH ок, так такую предлагаете последовательность, чтобы в случае чего не наломать дров.?

Comment: @xaja айболитом вроде бы вытравил заразу, 2 часа как все работает хорошо, буду наблюдать - а как теперь уберечься от нее на будущее? какую защиту поставить?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/ Хороший, помогает, тем что может устанавливать ограничения на файлы. Обновить сам Wordpress, обновить сторонние плагины, которые не завязаны на теме (а то можно тему сломать). Ограничить ftp по ip https://peterhost.ru/wiki/.ftpaccess/

Comment: @xaja только вот это "ограничить ftp по ip" я думаю, не очень возможно. ip у хостера динамические, к тому же приходится заходить с разных мест... а в связи с адресным кризисом в ближайшие годы, пока все массово не перейдут на ip6 - статический ip будет очень дорого иметь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А у вас хостинг или VPS? Просто если хостинг - там же должен быть антивирус. У меня несколько сайтов хостится в [RigWEB](https://rigweb.ru) (не реклама) - вирусы сразу удаляются.
А если у вас сервер - то рекомендую использовать скрипт Айболита, или антивирус maldet в связке с clamav. Так же посмотрите антивирус от яндекса https://yandex.ru/promo/manul

Comment: спс, но я уже решил проблему о чем и написал в описании

Answer (score 5):

В принципе конечно вы нашли правильный find. большой процент хакерского софта использует именно такой способ шифрования и запуска. Но большой - это далеко не 100%.

Может быть и простенькая строчка `if(isset($_GET['A'])) eval($_GET['A']);`
Ну правда эта строчка - просто удобный способ входа для хакера и выполнения произвольного кода.

Учитывая, что меняются .htaccess для мобильников видимо это автоматический червь, который рассылает вирусы на мобильные устройства. И раз файлы меняются часто - значит заражен один из ваших .php файлов.

Можете перелить к себе на машину полную копию сайта и поискать просто слово eval, правда некоторые CMS сами этим пользуются. Кроме того часто запуск шифрованного кода выполняется хитро составленным preg_replace.

В 90% случаев код червя обфусцирован и/или шифрован. И представляет собой сложночитаему белиберду. можно просто беглым просмотром php файлов попробовать найти такие куски.

Можно попробовать ориентироваться на дату изменения файлов, правда грамотные хакеры по хорошему должны ее восстанавливать после записи, но по моим наблюдениям они этим особенно не заморачиваются.

НО, все вышеперечисленное не дает никакой гарантии, что вы найдете все закладки хакера и вычистите их. И тем более никаких гарантий, что вас на заразят вновь, раз сделали это уже однажды. По хорошему, если у вас какой то стандартный движок без изменений на уровне .php файлов - то вам надо просто сделать архив текущего сайта, архив базы, после чего развернуть заново движок и перенести конфиг файл из текущего сайта, убедившись, что в конфиге нет строк eval и preg_replace.

НО, и это не дает никаких гарантий, раз к вам попали - значит в используемом вами софте на сайте есть уязвимости и червь опять их найдет. Можете просто в интернете на вашу версию движка и плагинов к нему поискать в гугле на слово exploit. Посмотреть так же например на [Exploit DB](https://www.exploit-db.com/)

Самое надежное - сохранить базу от текущего сайта, поискать в дампе базы слова 'eval' (на некоторых движках внедрение возможно через содержимое базы данных) и установить на сайт самую свежую версию движка и необходимых плагинов, заодно посмотрев инфу о их безопасности в интернете. Ну и запустить вместо установки апгрейд предыдущей базы до новой версии.

И есть какая то вероятность, что забрались к вам через соседей на хостинге (хотя для автоматических червей она крайне низка). Если на хостинге проблемы с безопасностью, определить это можно при определенном опыте, попробовав самому добраться до каталогов других сайтов.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать. по результатам отпишусь

Comment: стоит добавить, что чаще всего код добавляют так, чтобы его было трудно увидеть. Например, пишут `<?php`, потом куча пробелов и вредоносный код одной строчкой. Тогда, делая просмотр кода, если редактор не вписывает длинные строки по экрану, можно не заметить что где-то дальше в строке есть код.

Comment: Замечу, что при скачивании всех файлов к себе на машину многие шеллы будут отловлены антивирусом.

Comment: Спасибо, @Mike! заразу вроде вытравил - а как теперь защититься от нее на будущее? движки сайтов wordpress

Comment: @Вася последнюю версию вордпресса поставить ну и если плагины какие то есть, от их то же до последней версии обновить. Как именно вордпресс обновляется я не знаю, в гугле на "обновление wordpress"  инфы вроде много

Comment: @Mike да, последние поставил - шелл пролез через плагин tinymce compat3x, во всяком случае там локализовался

Comment: @Вася Пароли еще под которыми на управление вордпрессом заходите, поменяйте, в системе мог быть логгер который отсылал пароли хакерам

Answer (score 0):

Нужно искать сторонний файл на хостинге в папках где лежат сайты. Сделай выборку новых, и ищи подозрительные. Его соответственно убить. и далее искать по логам дыру в одном из сайтов.

Comment: А посторонние файлы не обязательны. Часто внедряют кусок в index.php или другой, загружаемый им файл. И этот кусок реагирует на наличие конкретного GET или POST параметра. Кроме того, по моим наблюдениям безопасность у 20% хостеров налажена так плохо, что при попадании на один ресурс на хостинге злоумышленник получает доступ ко всем. Т.е. даже нет 100% уверенности, что вход именно через его сайт